# Using dplyr/ggplot2 inside for loops

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to filter and plot 11 different graphs based on 11 different levels from a column stored in a vector.

For a quick, reproducible example, here's basically something I've tried:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)
positions = c("forward", "defense")

df <- data.frame(player = c("Sergio Ramos", "Lionel Messi",
                            "Dani Alvez", "Christiano Ronaldo"),
                 position = c("forward", "defense", "defense", "forward"),
                 goals = c(12, 8, 2, 23))

for (i in 1:length(positions)) {
  df %>%
    filter(position == positions[i]) %>%
    print(ggplot(aes(x = player, y = goals)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity"))
}
```

If I just wrap the filter in `print()` and run it, I get both subsets:

```
             player position goals
1       Sergio Ramos  forward    12
2 Christiano Ronaldo  forward    23
        player position goals
1 Lionel Messi  defense     8
2   Dani Alvez  defense     2
```

But the code above gives me

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval.

If I run the code without the loop, it graphs fine.

I want to be able to loop through the variables and publish them all in Rmd or save them all. Can someone explain why the above does not work? Thanks!

Comment: This `ggplot(df, aes(x = player, y = goals)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +facet_wrap(~position)` ?

Answer (score 5):

Using the dplyr pipes puts the data frame in wrong place. Try like this instead:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
positions = c("forward", "defense")

df <- data.frame(player = c("Sergio Ramos", "Lionel Messi",
                            "Dani Alvez", "Christiano Ronaldo"),
                 position = c("forward", "defense", "defense", "forward"),
                 goals = c(12, 8, 2, 23))

for (i in 1:length(positions)) {
  df %>%
    filter(position == positions[i]) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = player, y = goals)) +
            geom_bar(stat = "identity") -> g
    print(g)
}
```

You may also consider rewriting the loop with lapply.

Comment: Why do you assign the ggplot2 object at the end of the call?

Comment: If I stack it like this `df %>% filter(position == positions[i]) %>% gplot(aes(x = player, y = goals)) +  geom_bar(stat = "identity") %>% print()` , it only prints text info about the geom.

Comment: More of a syntax question. I thought typical R convention was to assign objects on the left side so I was just wondering if this was an exception or had some purpose.

Comment: I find it easier to follow, when pipelining with `%>%` , but I agree, left hand assignment is more conventional.

Comment: This solution best fits my needs currently I think. I tried using `facet_wrap()`, but it doesn't really seem to come out that great if you have more than a few values to facet by, and more than a few x values.

Comment: Is there a way to put a custom subtitle for each ggplot graph, based on the values in 'positions' -- +labs(subtitle = ?)

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need any kind of loop to get what you need. The `facet_wrap` can do what you need. i.e.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = player, y = goals)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +facet_wrap(~position)
```

Comment: When your data is bigger (i.e. you have more than 4 values as your x), the x becomes unreadable (the names overlap heavily). Is there some way to get around this?

Comment: You can use `make.unique()` on the names to avoid overlapping

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have all the plots in one place independently *(without using facet_wrap)*, you can try the following:

- split the dataframe into groups defined by position as a factor.

  `dfx <- split(df,as.factor(df$position))`

**lapply Solution**

Also you can use lapply on the splitted dataframe as follows:

- define a function that produce the plot you want

  `my_plot <- function(x){
          g <- ggplot(x,aes(x = player, y = goals)) +
                  geom_bar(stat = "identity") 
          }`
- use lapply

`ggy <- lapply(dfx,my_plot)`

You will have all plots in ggy:

```
ggy$defense
ggy$forward
```

**for-loop solution**

- create an empty list to keep all plots in.

  `ggx <- list()`
- loop and save each plot in ggx list.

  ```
  for(i in 1:length(positions)){
      # create a barplot and save in g
      g <- ggplot(dfx[[i]],aes(x = player, y = goals)) +
              geom_bar(stat = "identity")

      n <- dfx[[i]]$position %>% unique() %>% as.character()

      # add the plot to the list
      ggx[[n]] <- g
  ```

  }

now you have the plots in:

```
ggx[[1]] or ggx$defense
ggx[[2]] or ggx$forward
```

You can print wherever you want, save or get information.

```
> ggx$defense$data
        player position goals
2 Lionel Messi  defense     8
3   Dani Alvez  defense     2
```

Comment: Probably the fullest answer

Answer (score 1):

The below will save a plot to each page of a pdf in your working directory

```
pdf("out.pdf", width = 7, height = 7)
for (i in 1:length(positions)) {
 print( df %>%
    filter(position == positions[i]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = player, y = goals)) +
            geom_bar(stat = "identity"))
}
dev.off()
```

For markdown documents start with [the markdown cheat sheet here](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/).

However I think you may want to look into using the `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap` function and saving that to pdf in the same method as above

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way too:

```
for (i in positions) {
  dfplt <- df %>%
    filter(position == positions) 
    plt <- ggplot(dfplt,aes(x = player, y = goals)) +
            geom_bar(stat = "identity")
    ggsave(plt, file=paste0(i,"_plot.png"))
}
```